# Relationship between base resistor and collector current in this unbalanced differential amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, differential-amplifier

For this BJT circuit, I was wondering if there was a solution for how the collector currents change with respect to the value of the single base resistor.  This arrangement popped up in a circuit I was trying to understand and I noticed that my DC analysis was wrong because I couldn't figure out how to account for Rb.

The simulation shows the expected result of splitting the bias supply equally among the transistors for a zero ohm base resistor and as the resistance increases the T2 base current is reduced causing the bias current to be shunted to the T1 transistor.

So far I have come up with \$Ic_2=\frac{\alpha I_{bias}}{1+e^{I_{B_2}R_B/V_T}}=\frac{\alpha I_{bias}}{1+e^{I_{C_2}R_B/\beta V_T}}\$.  Can this be simplified? Am I on the right track?

[image: Circuit Diagram of differential amplifier with single base resistor]

[image: collector currents for different values of base resistor]

Comment: With 0.058 volts across that resistor, you should have 10:1 current imbalance. Does your math predict that?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf How did you calculate 0.058 V across Rb?  I've been trying to find a closed form solution but come up short and instead tried an iterative approach where I initially assume \$I_{E1}\$ and \$I_{E2}\$ are both \$0.5I_{bias}\$.  This allows me to calculate \$V_E\$ from \$V_{BE1}\$ and \$V_{B2}\$ from \$I_{B2}\$ (\$I_{B2}=I_{E2}/(\beta+1)\$) to get the voltage drop across \$R_{b}\$.  This gives \$V_{EB2}\$ which gets me a new \$I_{E2}\$.  Since \$I_{E1}+I_{E2}=I_{bias}\$ I can then iterate back to \$I_{E1}\$ but currently this isn't converging anywhere near the SPICE values.

Comment: @FrankM. If you are still looking for a closed form solution, let me know. Are you familiar with the product-log function?